# Comunicación entre componentes hijos Angular

Tags: angular

Me gustaría poder llamar a los métodos que tiene un componente hijo desde otro componente que es hijo del mismo padre pero a un nivel mas bajo. Visto esquematicamente:

```
           |--Hijo B
 Padre A---|
           |--Hijo C---|--Hijo D
```

A es el padre de todos y tiene dos hijos B y C. C es a la vez el padre de D.

En mi aplicación de Angular el componente B posee una instancia de un mapa y funciones para manejar dicho mapa. C es un componente router que va cambiando el componente D según la aplicación lo requiera.

**Componente A**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

**HTML componente A**

```
<ng-container>
   <mat-sidenav-container> 
      <mat-sidenav>
         <!--Componente C-->
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content >
        <!--Componente B-->
        <app-map></app-map>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
   </mat-sidenav-container>
</ng-container>
```

**Componente B**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})


    export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
      ngOnInit(){...}
      dibujarCapaWMS(nombreCapa:string){...}
      borrarCapaWMS(){...}
      dibujarCoordenadas(coordenadas:any){...}
      obtenerMapaDeIDENA(){...}
      //......//
    }
```

**HTML componente B**

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div> <!--Openlayers map-->
```

**Componente C**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/inicio', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'inicio', component: PaginaInicioComponent },
  { path: 'edificios', component: EdificiosComponent },
  { path: 'parkings', component: ParkingsComponent },
  //..........//
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**El componente D es cambiado por el router** (uno de ellos)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edificios',
  templateUrl: './edificios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edificios.component.css']
})
export class EdificiosComponent implements OnInit {
  //........//
 /* Quiero llamar a las funciones de MapComponent desde aqui */
}
```

El componente B siempre es el mismo, y solamente modifica los valores de sus atributos mediante sus funciones. Se trata de una aplicación "tipo Google Maps" en la que el mapa es el mismo y va cambiando según que le mande que haga el componente D.

Comment: Si, he visto el artículo, pero ahi dice cómo compartir datos entre componentes. Lo que me gustaría es llamar a un método de otro componente cuando son parientes.

Comment: El componente A tendrá que hacer de *director de orquesta*, escuchando a un hijo para modificar los *inputs* del otro. Llamar a métodos directamente no lo recomendaría, creas una dependencia bidireccional que te puede causar más problemas. En su lugar es mejor *escuchar* eventos y actuar

Comment: Pero B tiene muchos métodos, ya que en él estoy trabajando con un mapa y tendría funciones para pintar capas, borrarlas, hacer peticiones a servidores etc. Crees que sería mejor hacer un switch muy grande en A que eligiera a que métodos de B llamar en funcion del mensaje que le pase el hijo C a traves de D, en vez de que D llamara directamente a los métodos de B?

Comment: Sin ver el código no puedo dar una respuesta. Quizá un servicio intermedio sea lo que necesitas: un componente llama a métodos del servicio, y el otro escucha diferentes eventos emitidos por dicho servicio. De ese modo rompes la dependencia entre componentes: si uno de ellos no existe, el otro sigue funcionando (emitiendo aunque no se le escuche, o escuchando aunque nadie mande nada)

Comment: Te recomiendo leerte el [tour] para entender cómo funciona el sitio y qué es un [mcve]

Comment: Tienes razon, pero es un problema que me he encontrado en un proyecto muy grande y no sabía muy bien como sintetizarlo poniendo un ejemplo. Voy a borrar este post y volver a formularlo correctamente

Comment: Si vas a poner código, puedes poner lo básico aquí y luego un enlace a stackblitz.com

Comment: Ya he puesto algo de código, espero aclarar un poco cual es el problema. A ver que solución crees que es la más acertada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo usaría un servicio para comunicar los elementos, porque no tienen una relación directa entre sí y sobrecargar la lógica de sus respectivos padres complicaría mucho el código. Te pongo un ejemplo básico:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

En tu caso, si quieres evitar un switch para ver qué tipo de mensaje es, podrías crear varios Subjects (para cada tipo de evento), y tus componentes podrían enviar/escuchar diferentes tipos de mensajes en diferentes métodos:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

    private subjectAccion1 = new Subject<any>();

    private subjectAccion2 = new Subject<any>();

    hazAccion1(message: string) {
        this.subjectAccion1.next({ text: message });
    }

    hazAccion2(message: string) {
        this.subjectAccion2.next({ text: message });
    }

    escucharAccion1(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subjectAccion1.asObservable();
    }

    escucharAccion2(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subjectAccion2.asObservable();
    }

    ...

}
```

Entonces el componente que espera órdenes se suscribiría al servicio:

```
constructor(private msgService: MessageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.observer1 = msgSer.escucharAccion1().subscribe(mensaje => this.cambiarAlgo1(mensaje));
  this.observer2 = msgSer.escucharAccion2().subscribe(mensaje => this.cambiarAlgo2(mensaje));
  //...
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.observer1.unsubscribe();
  this.observer2.unsubscribe();
}
```

¡No te olvides cancelar la subscripción o tendrás *memory-leaks*!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me has hecho un gran favor resolviéndome esto.