# llamar un metodo a otro componente angular ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic

Tengo el siguiente código en un componente llamado tab2.page.ts. Este código hace referencia a un calendario donde puedo hacer un CRUD de Eventos, el cual funciona todo como se quiere.

```
        import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
    import { CalendarComponent } from "ionic2-calendar/calendar";

    import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';


    import { AlertController, PopoverController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

    import { Tab2PopoverComponent } from '../tab2-popover/tab2-popover.component';
    import { UserService } from '../servicios/user.service';
    import { User } from 'firebase';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tab2',
      templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
    })
    export class Tab2Page {



      event = {
        title: '',
        desc: '',
        startTime: '',
        endTime: '',
        allDay: false
      };

      minDate = new Date().toISOString();

      eventSource = [];

      calendar = {
        mode: 'week',
        currentDate: new Date()
      }

      viewTittle = '';
      @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCal: CalendarComponent;
      constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,) { }
      resetEvent() {
        this.event = {
          title: '',
          desc: '',
          startTime: new Date().toISOString(),
          endTime: new Date().toISOString(),
          allDay: false
        };

      }





      //Agrega eventos

      addEvent() {
        let eventCopy = {
          title: this.event.title,
          startTime: new Date(this.event.startTime),
          endTime: new Date(this.event.endTime),
          allDay: this.event.allDay,
          //desc: this.event.desc
        }

        if (eventCopy.allDay) {
          let start = eventCopy.startTime;
          let end = eventCopy.endTime;

          eventCopy.startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate()));
          eventCopy.endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate() + 1));
        }

        this.eventSource.push(eventCopy);
        this.myCal.loadEvents();
        this.resetEvent();

      }





      next() {
        var swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container')['swiper'];
        swiper.slideNext();
      }

      back() {
        var swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container')['swiper'];
        swiper.slidePrev();
      }

      // Change between month/week/day
      changeMode(mode) {
        this.calendar.mode = mode;
      }

      today() {
        this.calendar.currentDate = new Date();
      }

      //mirar el evento y eliminar.
      async onEventSelected(event) {
        // Use Angular date pipe for conversion
        let start = formatDate(event.startTime, 'medium', this.locale);
        let end = formatDate(event.endTime, 'medium', this.locale);

        const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
          header: event.title,
          subHeader: event.desc,
          message: 'From: ' + start + '<br><br>To: ' + end,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('ok clicked' );
              console.log(event)
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Eliminar',
            handler: () => {

              console.log(this.eventSource);
               for (let index =0; index <= this.eventSource.length; index++) {
                 if (this.eventSource[index] === event) {
                  this.eventSource.splice(index, 1)
                  this.presentLoading();
                  console.log('Eliminar clicked: ' + index );
                  console.log(event);
                  this.myCal.loadEvents();

                 }



               }

            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Editar',
            handler: () => {
              for (let index =0; index <= this.eventSource.length; index++) {
                if (this.eventSource[index] === event) {
                  let newEvent = {
                    title: this.event.title,
                    startTime: new Date(this.event.startTime),
                    endTime: new Date(this.event.endTime),
                    allDay: this.event.allDay,
                    desc: this.event.desc
                  }

                  if (newEvent.allDay) {
                    let start = newEvent.startTime;
                    let end = newEvent.endTime;

                    newEvent.startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate()));
                    newEvent.endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate() + 1));
                  }

                  this.eventSource.push(newEvent);
                  this.myCal.loadEvents();
                  //this.resetEvent();
                  this.eventSource.splice(index, 1)
                }
              }


              console.log('Editar clicked');


              this.presentLoading();
              this.myCal.loadEvents();
            }
          }
          ]
        });


        alert.present();
      }



      async presentLoading() {
        const loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
          message: "Por favor, espera...",
          duration: 1000

        });
        loader.present();
      }









      onViewTitleChanged(title) {
        this.viewTittle = title;
      }

      onTimeSelected(ev) {
        let selected = new Date(ev.selectedTime);
        this.event.startTime = selected.toISOString();
        selected.setHours(selected.getHours() + 1);
        this.event.endTime = (selected.toISOString());

      }

}
```

Quiero usar el método de **addEvent()** en otro componente, ya que por cuestión de diseño, me piden usar el formulario de eventos en un Ion-Split (otro componente llamado **menu-cal.page.ts**, el de abajo).

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../servicios/user.service';
import { Tab2Page  } from "../tab2/tab2.page";
import { CalendarComponent } from "ionic2-calendar/calendar";
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs.page';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-cal',
  templateUrl: './menu-cal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-cal.page.scss'],
})
export class MenuCalPage implements OnInit {

  selectedPath='';



  constructor(private router: Router, private us: UserService, private t2: Tab2Page) {
    this.router.events.subscribe ((event: RouterEvent) =>{
      this.selectedPath = event.url;
    });


   }



  ngOnInit() {


  }

  addEvent(){
   return this.t2.addEvent()
  }
```

y este es su codigo html **menu-cal.hmtl**

```
<ion-split-pane >
  <ion-menu side="end">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content fullscreen class="calendario2">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]" [class.active-item]="selectedPath === p.url">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-card>
          <ion-card-header tappable (click)="collapseCard = !collapseCard">
            <ion-card-title>Nueva tarea</ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-header>
         <ion-card-content *ngIf="!collapseCard">
              <ion-item>
                  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Describe tu tarea" [(ngModel)]="event.title"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Hora de inicio</ion-label>
                    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm" pickerFormat="MMM D:HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="event.startTime" [min]="minDate"></ion-datetime>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Hora final</ion-label>
                    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm" pickerFormat="MMM D:HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="event.endTime" [min]="minDate"></ion-datetime>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Todo el día?</ion-label>
                    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="event.allDay"></ion-checkbox>
                  </ion-item>
                  <ion-button fill="outline" expand="block" (click)="addEvent()"  >Add Event</ion-button>


          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>


      </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet  main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

lo que sucede es que, si llamo el metodo como esta especificado en **menu-call.pag.ts**, el HtML me arroja lo siguiente en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así mismo 127 errores con la mismo descripción.

supongo que debe ser por como estoy llamando el método de agregar o no se. Agradecería su apoyo.
 Saludos :D

Comment: No acabo de enteder cómo recibes un componente en el constructor de otro componente...

Comment: Supongo que no he entendido muy bien aquella cuestión, por eso pido algo de ayuda hehe

Comment: Te aconsejo leer [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176463/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-componentes-que-se-muestran-en-diferentes-vistas-angular-5/176470#176470) y [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249188/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-componentes-hijos-angular/249219#249219)

Answer (score -1):

pon el método `addEvent()` estático `Static addEvent()`, en el componente donde  quieras usar el metodo importa el componente que tiene el metodo, y para usar el metodo solo pones el nombre del componente seguido de un punto y el nombre del metodo.

Ejemplo:

```
ComponentA 

Static addEvent()

ComponentB
 
obtenerComponentA()

  ComponentA.addEvent();
```

espero le sirva a otros usuarios saludos